# React Native google sign in and authentication using firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-signin

How to do authentication and sign in to google from react native and storing the access token to firebase for future autologin to account ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is here :

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

For the documentation :

https://rnfirebase.io/

More precisely for the authentication :

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/auth/social-auth

Every steps is explained, as you will need quite some configuration on firebase and apps

Comment: I did as u suggested. I am now getting the consent screen. But after giving username and password I am getting this error:    Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR
    at new GoogleSigninError (node_modules\react-native-google-signin\src\GoogleSignin.android.js:55)
    at node_modules\react-native-google-signin\src\GoogleSignin.android.js:131

Please help.

Comment: did you activate the google signin in the firebase console ?

Comment: yes. I started new project to isolate the issue. Now I am getting this issue:  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']
   > Cannot invoke method split() on null object